# Youtube 3D isn't working with nVidia 3D Vision

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, youtube, 3d-vision

I'm trying to watch a recently uploaded 3D video on Youtube using my nVidia 3D Vision capable system.  If I go through the help pages, I come to [one](http://www.3dvisionlive.com/3dv-html5-detection) which displays the information below:

[image: Proof 3D is working]

Additionally, I can watch the 3d Videos from that site fine.  However, none of the Youtube videos which are supposedly supported work.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 11 and Youtube 3D don't get along.  Switching over to the beta channel of Firefox and upgrading to Firefox 12 fixes the issue and allows 3D videos to be viewed properly with nVidia 3D Vision.

There are some issues, like 3D Vision not completely turning off when the Youtube tab is closed, thus messing with the screen brightness until Firefox is closed, but at least the transmitter and glasses turn off.